# Assistance in creating simple model matrix in order to block a factorial design

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, tibble

I'm having trouble creating a simple model matrix I could use to block a $2^5$ factorial design. In order to perform the blocking I was going to use the "Defining Contrast Method" which involves the expression $L = \alpha_1x_1 \dots + \alpha_kx_k$. Where $x_i$ is the level of $i$th factor and $\alpha_i$ is the exponent on the $i$th factor. To use this approach I needed to create a matrix with all of the possible binary combinations that could come about from my five factors. Below is the code of what I'm trying to do.

```
library(tidyverse)

a = c(0,1,0,0,1)
b = c(0,0,1,0,1)
c = c(0,0,0,1,0)
d = c(0,0,1,0,1)

help_tibble = tibble(a,b,c,d)
help_tibble
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>       a     b     c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0     0     0
#> 2     1     0     0     0
#> 3     0     1     0     1
#> 4     0     0     1     0
#> 5     1     1     0     1

block = (help_tibble[,1] + help_tibble[,2] + help_tibble[,3] + help_tibble[,4]) %% 2
block
#>   a
#> 1 0
#> 2 1
#> 3 0
#> 4 1
#> 5 1
```

So as an example what I'm trying to do is create the matrix at the bottom, but in the full design I would have 32 rows indicating which variables are being used. I wanted to use the `model.matrix()` command or something similar to it, but the problem that is going to arise is that I don't have a `block` variable yet. That will be assigned once I perform the mathematical operation using the `define_contrast_formula`. Preferably I would like to perform the calculation and add the column of respective $0$ and $1$ to the matrix I have which I think I can just append my `block` variable that I defined in the bottom part of my code.

So it appears the main issue is creating the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I have found the solution. You can use either `expand.grid` or `gen.factorial()` from the `AlgDesign` package:

```
test_grid
#>    A B C D E
#> 1  0 0 0 0 0
#> 2  1 0 0 0 0
#> 3  0 1 0 0 0
#> 4  1 1 0 0 0
#> 5  0 0 1 0 0
#> 6  1 0 1 0 0
#> 7  0 1 1 0 0
#> 8  1 1 1 0 0
#> 9  0 0 0 1 0
#> 10 1 0 0 1 0
#> 11 0 1 0 1 0
#> 12 1 1 0 1 0
#> 13 0 0 1 1 0
#> 14 1 0 1 1 0
#> 15 0 1 1 1 0
#> 16 1 1 1 1 0
#> 17 0 0 0 0 1
#> 18 1 0 0 0 1
#> 19 0 1 0 0 1
#> 20 1 1 0 0 1
#> 21 0 0 1 0 1
#> 22 1 0 1 0 1
#> 23 0 1 1 0 1
#> 24 1 1 1 0 1
#> 25 0 0 0 1 1
#> 26 1 0 0 1 1
#> 27 0 1 0 1 1
#> 28 1 1 0 1 1
#> 29 0 0 1 1 1
#> 30 1 0 1 1 1
#> 31 0 1 1 1 1
#> 32 1 1 1 1 1
```